# Does Quantum Darwinism select against the Frauchiger-Renner inconsistent states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-interpretations

Zurek's [Quantum Darwinism](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5082) is based on an environment induced superselection of pointer states, within which entanglement plays an essential role. Similar arguments can be made related to Horodecki's Spectrum Broadcast Theory.

The [Frauchiger-Renner experiment](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-018-05739-8) questions whether quantum theory has universal validity, whether it is possible to employ quantum theory to model complex systems that include agents who are themselves using quantum theory. The result is that sometimes (with small probability) the agent's conclusions can be inconsistent.

**Question**. Does Quantum Darwinism select against these Frauchiger-Renner inconsistent states, thus making these inconsistencies practically observable only with vanishing small probability (virtually unobservable)? In other words does Quantum Darwinism make these potential  inconsistencies practically irrelevant in real experiments?